# Is there a connection between Mallory Archer and Lucille Bluth?

Tags: arrested-development, archer

While checking my emails I got one from EB Games showcasing iconic mums from gamea and pop culture to celebrate Mother's Day, characters like Leia Organa, Aunt May, Molly Weasely and Morticia Adams just to name some.

One of the mums featured was Mallory Archer but out of all of them she was coupled with a second person, Lucille Bluth.

[image: Mallory and Lucille]

I know it's not because she's animated because there's video game characters there are other animated mums in the list, Nani Pelekai from *Lilo & Stitch* and Helen Parr from *The Incredibles*.

All I know about Lucille Bluth is that she's from *Arrested Development* but beyond that I don 't understand if there is any connection between the two besides an apparent similarity in attitude to their family.

So is there another connection between these 2 characters?

Answer (score 7):

The first and obvious connection is that they are both played by [Jessica Walter](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0910055/?ref_=tt_cl_t9), making them obvious grounds for going together.

A second connection is that they both play somewhat similar roles - the mother figure who behaves in a far from traditional "motherly" role. "Taking no attitude" and "queen of sass" is the description from your image, and both roles certainly display a "tough love" attitude towards their children (if going with the more charitable interpretation of their character).

Comment: Note that the similarities run much deeper in the details (though this answer gets the gist right so +1 from me). They're both considered posh, drink during the day, consider themselves to be significantly above the average person and mistreats those she considers below her, is oblivious to her own flaws and generally incapable of admitting making mistakes, is a skilled negotiator that can drive a hard bargain, master manipulator, openly-but-passively racist, unerringly stubborn and indomitable, ... The two characters are, by virtue of their personalities, virtually interchangeable.